# MYSQL select 2 diffrent Fields with same value from different lines

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
ID   APARTMENT_ID   CHECK_IN       CEHCK_OUT 
1    2              2014-18-07     2014-18-09
2    2              2015-01-01     2014-03-02
3    3              2014-08-01     2014-09-01
4    3              2014-09-01     2014-12-09
5    4              2014-18-07     2014-18-09
```

I want to get the ID, `APARTMENT_ID` and `CHECK_IN` , `CEHCK_OUT` . where there is on the same date in different ID.
on this table the query will bring the result of

```
APARTMENT_ID => 3
ID => 3, 4 
CHECK_IN CEHCK_OUT => 2014-09-01.
```

i tried something like

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` 
WHERE `ID` != `ID` and `CHECK_IN`=`CEHCK_OUT`
```

but its not the right way , 0 results.
thanks to anyone that could help me.

Comment: Your example seems wrong. Shouldn't the result be `APARTMENT_ID = 3, ID = 3, 4`?

Comment: You right. fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a self-join, otherwise you're just comparing fields in the same row:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o1
JOIN orders o2 ON o1.id != o2.id AND o1.check_in = o2.check_out
```

Comment: I think you need `ON o1.id > o2.id` to exclude symmetrical cases.

Comment: @PM77-1 If we were comparing the same other field in both rows I would do that. But since we're comparing `check_in` to `check_out`, there's no symmetry.